# restart scrapy using jobdir when running as a stand alone script

Tags: scrapy

I run my crawler like this

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
    from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

    s = get_project_settings()
    process = CrawlerProcess(s)
    process.crawl(MySpider)
    process.start()
```

And i use custom settings which has

```
"JOBDIR": "crawler_1",
```

If the crawler fails how do i restart it from the point of failure ?

Comment: assuming the JOBDIR captured all the persistent data accurately, then all you should need to do is run it again.  Scrapy will automatically see the JOBDIR in your settings and will check if there is any persistent data from previous runs

Comment: Hi Alexander Thanks again for coming to my rescue please make your comment as an answer and I will accept it so community can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `JOBDIR` captured all the persistent data accurately, then all you should need to do is run it again.

Scrapy will automatically see the `JOBDIR` in your settings and will check if there is any persistent data from previous runs.